# Compatiblity on NavigationView and Toolbar in Kitkat

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-design, navigationview

i'm trying to run the project and its really cool in Lollipop devices(designs and etc.without any problem)

But there is a problem in this project and i havent any experiences about this compatiblity in `Kitkat`.after installing:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2lFx.png
 I'm using : https://github.com/AkashBang/NavigationView

and here is the activty main:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/v"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/tool_bar">
            </include>

            <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
                android:id="@+id/slider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="175dp"
                android:elevation="2dp"
                custom:auto_cycle="true"
                custom:indicator_visibility="invisible"
                custom:pager_animation="Accordion"
                custom:pager_animation_span="1000" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btncat"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_home"
                android:paddingEnd="40dp"
                android:paddingStart="20sp"
                android:text="@string/category"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textDirection="ltr" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="3sp"
                card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/top_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cardview1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/rcrechome"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cardview1"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="180dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
                    card_view:cardElevation="3sp"
                    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cardview2"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="180dp"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cardview1"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
                    card_view:cardElevation="3sp"
                    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cardview3"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="180dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cardview2"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
                    card_view:cardElevation="3sp"
                    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/cardview3"
                    android:text="@string/morebtn"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Theme: for this activity**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">#43A047</item>

        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

Toolbar codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

But, i cant figured out, why this is gonna happened?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting this in V19 Layout and style, its working.

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```